# Storing images in the Android filesystem

Tags: android, android-studio, filesystems

An Android novice here.
I'm trying to complete a task which involves creating a simple app containing buttons on a single page. Each button, when clicked, should display the corresponding image.
One thing I don't understand in the instructions is that "the images should be stored on the phone filesystem rather than compiled into the application under
resources". What exactly does this mean? Do I need to load the images into the phone manually every time I try running the application? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: *What exactly does this mean?* Ask customer/employer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, int i ) {

    File file = new File (path+name.jpg);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method will save bitmap as a jpeg file on your phone.

P.S.

**path** - path of place where you want to save

**name** - name of image

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Is the path that of the image saved in the pc? Also, I have around 30 images to save in the filesystem, so do I need to do this for each image? Further clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: yes of course , for ech file you need to use this method

Answer (score 0):

Apps can include images in their resources/drawable folder that get added into the actual app .apk file. That makes them retrievable using R.drawable.image_name. Sounds like the instructions you are following does not want you do this. They want you to store them on the phone in the data/data/package file structure. If this is the case you can find plenty of examples on how to do this. The answer by Arsen Sench here does this.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it helped me understand better. Do you mind directing me to a tutorial that does this, or just tell me what I should search on Google for this?. And once I store the images, how do I retrieve them? Thanks once again for your help